# Whats best practice to access Model inside Command in MVVM pattern in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

Lets say I have a simple UI in `MainPage.xaml`

```
<ListView ItemSources="{Binding Records}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RecordTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

In `App.xaml`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RecordTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    <Button Content="Change title" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeTitleCommand,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to keep `Record` class as simple and clean as possible, only have one property `Title`.

In `MainViewModel.cs`, in `ChangeTitleCommand` I want to access to the Record model of the ListViewItem which I click on the button.

I can do it by cast the `sender` object to `FrameworkElement`, access the `DataContext`, cast it to `Record` type and start making change. But its ugly and require ViewModel to aware of the View (FrameworkElement), it make the ViewModel not reuseable in difference UI framework, so I want to avoid this approach.

One possibility is Bind to command in the Record class, not in the MainViewModel (remove the `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}` part). This way I get access to the model by `this` keyword. This way make my `Record` class become a mess as I add more functions and event-to-command to the `RecordTemplate`.

So which is the best practice to get access to the model from inside a Command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your template to the resources of `MainPage.xaml` and set to the `Command` property following:

```
{Binding ChangeTitleCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModelName}}.
```

Or you can set name for your page and write the following:

```
{Binding DataContext.ChangeTitleCommand, ElementName='pagename'}
```

Comment: i mentioned both methods in my question. But my question is how to access the model in command, not linking command to correct place.

Comment: Pass it by 'CommandParameter' property. For example:Command={Binding DataContext.ChangeTitleCommand, ElementName='pagename'}, CommandParameter={Binding }

Comment: It wont work in case I need the actual event args since Command support only 1 parameter. But I think this way is at least better then the 2 above.